# How save smarty template into db and then render that from controller in yii2?

Tags: yii2, twig, smarty

Im trying to develop a website with some users who can write blogs. 
In this site users need to be able to save their template created by `smarty` or `twig` to db and then i will render that from `db`.

Any one have any idea about how i render templates from database?

Comment: In addition to strangeqargo's answer, I'd recommend to take a look at custom template resources http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/resources.custom.tpl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/resources.string.tpl

load template from database ->into string -> render.

don't forget about caching and security though

it's harder to do with a twig (because of twig's inheritance), but - in a limited way - possible .

Comment: Thanks.  How i use this in controller?

Comment: oh, I don't remember Yii well, sorry. And I don't know your app architecture. I guess you should make some services/classes for storing/getting uploaded templates so they load correct templates from database by userId. I'm pretty sure there's google info on overloading Yii template loading.